# Convert first page of multi-page PDF file to PNG

Tags: imagemagick

How can you make imagemagick only output the first page as a file (PNG) if the PDF has multiple pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select the page (or pages) you want by adding `[NR]` to the filename. Example:

```
convert a.pdf[0] a.png[0]
```

Or with multiple pages:

```
convert a.pdf[0-3] a.png[0-3]
```